# Where does the rest of code or program wen t after I download it?

Tags: game-development

I know this a stupid question, but I am developing a game right now. And I need a reference, how to properly organize my file, and I already have some game on my pc. So I was thinking using those game's organized directory as my reference. But when I try to look at the game, all I could find is exe file, but where did the rest of the file went, the game I am referencing to is worth about 100GB and exe file is only 13KB. I know there are game models but I couldn't find those too. Did the game developer hid the file up?

I tried to google it, but no answer, could anyone please help me?

Comment: Look under %PROGRAMDATA% or %APPDATA%

Comment: The games that you download in playable form don't include source code. If they did, there would be no need to buy the game, because everyone could just pass around the source code and anybody could build it. That includes all the games that are pre-installed with Windows or download from the Windows Store.

Comment: I know it will not come with source code, but it didnt explain where is the rest of the file